# Python: Multi-threaded Command Line Animation

Tags: python, multithreading, command-line

I'm basically trying to create the **"loading bar"** effect using multithreading however the challenge is due to (what i assume at least) **sys.stdout.flush** it really doesn't create the effect that I am willing to make;

```
Starting .... Done!
Starting ....... Done! # Two of the has to work simultaneously
```

Just to make everything clear here is a **(should-be)** screenshots while program is working;

```
Starting ..
Starting .

Starting ...
Starting ..

Starting .... Done!
Starting ...
```

I was wondering if it is even **possible**? Here is the code that I've tried so far and did not worked out;

```
import time
import sys
import thread

def do_task():
    time.sleep(1)

def example_1(n, end_word):
    for i in range(n):
        do_task()
        print '\b.',
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print end_word + '!'

def func_1():
    print ''
    sys.stdout.write('Starting  ')
    example_1(3, 'Done')
def func_2():
    print ''
    sys.stdout.write('Starting  ')
    example_1(4, 'Done')

thread.start_new_thread(func_1, ())
thread.start_new_thread(func_2, ())

while 1:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) would do the job. 
Have a look at what is possible in this [example](http://blog.skeltonnetworks.com/2010/03/python-curses-custom-progress-bar/)